# Productory with lambda function in Python

Tags: python, lambda, python-requests

Suppose we have a function f(x) = f_1(x)f_2(x)...f_D(x). How can I implement this function f as a productory with a lambda function?

I need this to integrate a productory.

Example f_i = x[i]**m:

```
 lambda m: x[0]**m*x[1]**m*x[2]**m....x[D-1]**m
```

Comment: What is a "productory"? Do you mean "product"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really want to use `lambda`, you could pass one to [`functools.reduce`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/functools.html):

```
from functools import reduce

def product_integrate(values, m):
    return reduce(lambda x, y: x * y ** m, values)
```

Or as [@chepner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62127198/productory-with-lambda-function-in-python/62143106?noredirect=1#comment109906883_62143106) suggests in the comments, a more efficient solution would be to make use of [`operator.mul`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.mul):

```
from functools import reduce
from operator import mul

def product_integrate(values, m):
    return reduce(mul, values) ** m
```

**Usage:**

```
>>> product_integrate([1,2,3,4,5], 2)
14400
```

Comment: Or more efficiently, `reduce(operator.mul, values)**m`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use just a regular function instead. Simply iterate over the elements, take their power of m, and then multiply them into a result.

```
def integrate(values, m):
    result = 1
    for value in values:
        result *= (value ** m)
    return result
```